# How to build a has-a-relationship connection between a Pojo class and an abstract class using Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a class named Driver.Java, another class named Truck.Java and an abstract class named Vehicle.Java. A driver can drive several vehicles, truck, bus etc. I want to simulate this situation. Driver.Class and Vehicle.Class connects each other with has-a-relationship. Codes are below.

Driver.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DRIVER")

public class Driver {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private int driverId;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Vehicle vehicle;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="AGE")
private int age;

public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public Driver(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
public void setDriverId(int driverId) {
    this.driverId = driverId;
}
public int getDriverId() {
    return driverId;
}
```

Vehicle.Java

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Vehicle {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="BRAND")
private String brand;

@Column(name="COLOUR")
private String colour;

@Column(name="PRICE")
private int price;

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}
public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}
public String getColour() {
    return colour;
}
public void setColour(String colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
}
public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(int amount) {
    this.price = amount;
}

public abstract int totalCost();
public Vehicle(String brand, String colour, int price) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.price = price;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public Vehicle(){}  
}
```

Main

```
    Vehicle vehicle2 = new Truck("Mercedes", "White", 250);
    Driver driver = new Driver("Hakan Namlı", 36);
    driver.setVehicle(vehicle2);
    DriverDAO dDao = new DriverDAO();
    dDao.addDriver(driver);
```

DriverDAO.Java

```
public class DriverDAO {

private Session session;

public void addDriver(Driver driver){

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.save(driver);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(HibernateException ex){
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
}
```

HibernateUTIL.Java
    public class HibernateUtil {

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
        .configure()
        .addPackage("models") 
        .addAnnotatedClass(Driver.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(Vehicle.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(Truck.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(Bus.class)
        .buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property      
     name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>   
</session-factory>
```

This is the output:

```
1 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.5.2-Final
11 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.2-Final
12 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
14 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
17 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
75 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
79 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
79 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
128 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
128 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration - Mapping package models
146 [main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Package not found or wo package-info.java: models
154 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
177 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: models.Driver
201 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity models.Driver on table DRIVER
238 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: models.Truck
239 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity models.Truck on table TRUCK
241 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: models.Bus
241 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity models.Bus on table BUS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.DriverDAO.addDriver(DriverDAO.java:28)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

When i try to run this, object of SessionFactory class is returned null. So, i cannot generate a Session object and cannot save the data. It is not about hibernate config file, because i tried it in different scenarios. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: An object does not return anything. A method does. Show us the code you have problem with, and explain the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add @Inheritance annotation to class B.
You can also define which kind table is created for inherised class with @inheritance annotation by using strategy value like

```
@Inherintace(strategty = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

EDIT:

When you create your DriverDAO object with new keyword all it's attributes are has only defaul values and for all objects that is null.
You should initialize dDAO object with correct values

```
DriverDAO dDAO = new DriverDAOImpl();
dDAO.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
```

Or if you initialize DriverDAO in constructor please provide that code. Entity classes has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but it does not worked. Object of SessionFactory class is still returned null.

Comment: So yours bDAO.sessionFactory attribute is null? Then you have something wrong with yours dependecy injection configuration.
Please post yours hibernate configurations

Comment: Post the piece of code and config, which has got problem. The code you pasted has nothing to do with the problem you described. if possible, remove the code.

Comment: I put all the codes above. Thank you for your replies and patient.